# What is Quirks Mode categorized under Document Mode and how to Change it?

Tags: html, xhtml, browser, doctype, quirks-mode

I saw my pages information in IE8 Developer Tools.

My Page Document Mode was Quirks Mode.

What is **Quirks Mode** ? and How To change Document Mode ? What are the others document modes ?

How can Document Mode affect the Page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html