# Cross Browser Issue with the CSS in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, css

Below HTML Displays Menu in same line for FF latest version & Google Crome browsers but in IE9 it it show them in separate lines.

I want menu to be display in one line. I am not sure what i should do to fix this i tried several properties but didn't work as it works in FF & Crome.
Any help in this would be appreciated

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
  $("p").click(function()
{
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
 </script>

<style>
.test
{
    background-color: #B4984E;    
    border: 1px #ffffff solid;
    color: #fff;       
 line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 23px;
    text-decoration: none;      
  /* white-space: nowrap; display: block;*/       
 display: inline-block; 
    cursor:pointer;    
}    
</style>    
</head>
<body>    
<div class="test" href="http://Default.aspx?PageId=3&Language=en-US">HOME</div>    
<div class="test" href="http://PageId=5&Language=en-US">PROFILE</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Update: I cant use float:left in this one**

Answer (score 2):

Most important thing: `<div>`s are not links, and do not have `href`s. Use the anchor tag: `<a>`.

Next most important thing: You need a [doctype](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/doctypes) or your page will be rendered in ["quirks mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode) (in other words, very badly). The standard doctype these days is the html5 doctype, which is simply:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Put this at the top of your page, before the `<html>` tag.

That alone might solve your issue, but as a wild guess you might want to try `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` (although that *should* already work).

Comment: I agree with you Actually i am tried us string builder in C# to build a string similar to <div class="test" onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" >
hello</div> BUT string builder generates I agree with you Actually i am trying to string builder in C# to build a string similar to <div class="test" onclick='location.href='http://www.example.com';' >
hello</div> which doesn't work NOTICE the difference after onclick=' its ads single code rather than double quote somehow which doesn't work properly. I will implement other part of your suggestion & see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs that you want to be next to each other `float:left` properties and give them widths.

Comment: I want to achieve this without using float:left, float will resolve but i cant use this...

Comment: You're probably going to get a bunch of answers telling you to use floats. Maybe you should let everyone know in your description that you do not want to use floats and why?