# Javascript-Jquery-Ajax ticker message is truncated

Tags: javascript, ajax, ticker, truncated

In the following JavaScript code, when I pass the message is too big that spans more than one screen width, message is being truncated. I have put the alert statements and found out that the whole message is coming from web method to javascript code, but while displaying it, it is truncating the messsage. Since I am novice to JavaScript (this code is concoction of code bits I got from the web), any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //initialize ul;
    $("#scroller").html("");
    var tkhtml = '';
    var successReq = false;


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetDataFromWebMethod.aspx/GetDataForTicker",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            var y = msg.d;
            var x = y.split('~');
            alert(x.length);

            if (x != '') {
                for (n = 0; n < x.length; n++) {
                    tkhtml = tkhtml + '<li>' + x[n] + '</li>';
                }
                alert(tkhtml);
                $("#scroller").html(tkhtml);
                successReq = true;
            }
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert("Entered Failure");
        }

    });


    var successReq = false;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (successReq) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            javacode();
        }
    }, 100);

    function javacode() {
        var speed = 2;
        var items, scroller = $('#scroller');
        var width = 0;

        scroller.children().each(function() {
            width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });
        scroller.css('width', width);
        scroll();
        function scroll() {
            items = scroller.children();
            var scrollWidth = items.eq(0).outerWidth();
            scroller.animate({ 'left': 0 - scrollWidth }, scrollWidth * 100 / speed, 'linear', changeFirst);
        }
        function changeFirst() {
            scroller.append(items.eq(0).remove()).css('left', 0); scroll();
        }
    }


});
```

My css is:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    #scroller { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 30px; position: relative; } 
    #scroller li { float: left; height: 30px; padding: 0 0 0 10px; list-style-position: inside; }
    #scrollerWrapper { height: 30px; margin: 30px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px #333 solid; background: #F2F2F2; } 
</style>
```

Comment: what does your CSS look like?

Comment: MY CSS is: <style type="text/css">
        #scroller
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 30px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #scroller li
        {
            float: left;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 0 0 0 10px;
            list-style-position: inside;
        }
        #scrollerWrapper
        {
            height: 30px;
            margin: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px #333 solid;
            background: #F2F2F2;
        }
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have your `#scroller` set to `width:100%`, assuming your `body` or `html` is set as such it'll truncate to the window width. You should try `width:auto`

edit::

Ok, so each li is `float:left`, that takes it out of the standard flow of the document. Try using `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`

Comment: I have added width:auto in CSS. But it looks like how ever big my browser window is, the message is being trucated to that much width. I think the problem is at var scrollWidth = items.eq(0).outerWidth();. But I dod not know how to fix it. :-(

Comment: You are correct, JKirchartz! After I set the command to   scroller.css('width', 10000); instead of   scroller.css('width', width); it worked. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi JKirchartz, I have one more question, if you don't mind. When I run this program on my computer, the message stays with in the box. but when i published it on IIS server, the message overflows out side of the box on both sides. Could you please suggest any remedies? Thank you for your help.

Comment: And also the strange things is that it works ok on Firefox and Chrome but not on IE from the server. But it works fine on all browsers from my machine when I run the program.

Comment: I'm not sure, IIS shouldn't screw up your CSS... Might have to make a new question for that...

Comment: It seems it's getting interesting by the hour. Finally, I found out that because the setting called "Compatibility View" is on on IE browser window, it is overflowing out of the container. Because other browsers were not set to compatibility view, it was working fine with them. After I started undoing the compatibility view on my IE browser, it started working on IE too! But this code should work with either of the settings, though! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compatibility View is probably quirks mode, which is extremely broken and doesn't render CSS properly, best to avoid it. for more check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode to fix this usually involves a bunch of tricks like the css star hack. Paul Irish has a nice article explaining why old broken browsers get an old broken experience here http://paulirish.com/2011/tiered-adaptive-front-end-experiences/

Comment: By adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> in <Head> section of the HTMLfixed the problem for some applications. Thank you very much for your help.