# Internet explorer spacing issue pushes content down, CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I am fairly new to building websites using Java plugins and CSS. I have finished my site and looks great on safari, firefox, chrome and opera but if I check it on internet explorer there is a huge spacing issue. Here is teh url to the site: http://melisachamorro.com/ The content at the top of the "My Work" section gets broken into two lines which then pushes the rest of the content down. I used to fix spacing issues in IE by typing "*" or "_" before the value in my css. for example (_padding-left: 240px;). This doesn't seem to work anymore (last time I used that trick was two years ago so I'm sure it's totally obsolete by now). Any help or suggestions anyone can provide would be much much appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more info to clarify something. (Also please don't judge my "coding" too harshly, I know not what I do sometimes) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of IE? If it's very old, do you care? Most web-developers are no longer supporting lower versions of IE.

Comment: I'm seeing the problem on IE9

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of invalid HTML as per [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://melisachamorro.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Internet Explorer hates invalid HTML and might slip into [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) when it's encountered.  If you want a more consistent cross-browser experience, always validate your code.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695790/594235

Comment: Yup seems like I do have a bunch of invalid HTML. I'm going to go through those now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solid break down of how to create a IE only stylesheet. It sounds like your website is geared towards non-IE browsers. If IE is your customer's main browser I'd use a different approach.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Standardized code should be preferred over a bunch of conditional stylesheets.

Comment: In hindsight, I'd have to agree.