# VideoJS defaulting to Flash in IE9

Tags: html, video.js

For some reason that I can't make out, the player is defaulting to flash in IE, although it works just fine in Chrome and FF. I've added in all three recommended video formats (mp4, webm, and ogv).

http://www.bijouphotobooths.com/

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IE 9 renders your page in [quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode). While in quirks mode, IE can't play MP4 natively so the Flash fallback is needed.

If you open IE's developer tools (press F12) and switch the document mode from "Quirks" to "Internet Explorer 9 standards", you'll see the player on the reloaded page can now use the browser's native MP4 support.

Also try this in the console of developer tools. In quirks mode it will error because canPlayType is not a function.

```
document.createElement("video").canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529728/html5-doctype-putting-ie9-into-quirks-mode) for how to coax Internet Explorer into using standards mode.

Comment: Thanks so much, misterben! I'll look into this tonight.