# Doctype and quirksmode

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

Iv'd wanted to find out is it possible to change your IE mode after you'd set the doctype

Atm i can only set this specific doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

Which make IE turn into Quirks mode.
See **[this article](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/doctype/a/aaquirksmode.htm)** for more info about doctypes and quirksmode

I don't have the possibility to change this what can i do to change this to like the newest IE standard available ?

I can only change the html, css and javascript

I cant set meta tags or anything cause the service we sent it to have a build step that set everything this way

Summed up:

Change the mode of the browser with javascript after a page load?

Comment: Have you tried createDocumentType ?

Comment: i dont have access to the build step and the firm that makes this cant change it eather

Comment: I don't know of any way to trigger standards mode without changing the doctype. You could set up a reverse proxy and make it replace the doctype on all outgoing documents! -- On a more serious note - a system that doesn't let you set the doctype might be a system in need of replacement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, after the page has loaded and the doctype string and the `meta` tags have been parsed, nothing on the page can change the browser mode. The mode selection in IE is very complicated, see [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), but they have no provision for changing the mode via scripting.

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for Tough it wasn't what i hoped for

Answer (score -2):

IE automatically sets the rendering mode to Quirks mode if the Website is not valid HTML. You should try to use a validator (http://validator.w3.org/) to see what is wrong.

Comment: If you read the hole question isn't why it changes its can i change it back

Comment: Validity of HTML has little to do with the rendering mode chosen as far as I know. What's your source? (I'm downvoting until proven wrong) ;)

Comment: @xec — You're right, validity has nothing to do with it. Doctype that is the primary factor (I think some meta elements and possibly http headers may factor into it too … although only for IE).

Comment: @bouscher it works fine in my pure markup and its flawless down to ie7 so its some where in the build step

Comment: As far as I know, it is either a missing doctype declaration or invalid html, i.e. not complying with the doctype declaration, that triggers quirksmode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode

Comment: @bouscher You mean invalid **doctype**, rather than invalid html, I assume?

Comment: Actually I mean both: "Generally, quirks mode is turned on when there is no correct DOCTYPE declaration, and turned off when there is a DOCTYPE definition. However, invalid HTML - with respect to the chosen DOCTYPE - can also cause the browser to switch to quirks mode." (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode)

Comment: Anyway, doctype is readonly and I don't know of any method to change it with javascript. And even if it could be changed, I don't think that it would force the browser out of quirksmode after the page has been rendered already.

Comment: I think the referenced answer is wrong. I've never seen any evidence to suggest that invalid HTML can trigger quirks mode.

Comment: @Quentin Everything you said was right, I take everything back and stand corrected. So it is probably the missing system identifier ("http : //www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd") that causes the browser to trigger quirksmode.

Comment: It isn't the missing system identifier specifically. You can have an HTML 4.01 Strict Doctype without one and trigger standards mode. Having HTML 4.01 Transitional without a system identifier triggers quirks mode. There's little logic about it, it is based (AFAIK) on a popularity contest for "which doctype strings were most commonly used on websites that depended on quirks mode" that ran when IE6 came out.