# Why does html layout change when <!DOCTYPE html> is included?

Tags: html, css

Without `<!DOCTYPE html>` the following html:

```
<style>
input { width: 400px; }
span { width: 160px; display: inline-block; }
div { width: 560px; }
</style>
<div>
    <span>Slug</span><input type=text placeholder="enter-article-slug-here">
</div>
```

Renders like this in Chrome and FF:

[image: without doctype]

But when the line `<!DOCTYPE html>` is included, the html renders like this:

[image: with doctype]

Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is quirks mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare `<!DOCTYPE html>`, Chrome and Firefox will change `input` from `box-sizing: border-box` to `box-sizing: content-box`. Because the `input` text box has a `padding` of `1px` and a `border` of `1px`, this will increase the `width` by `4px` total, and in your example, that is enough to wrap it to the next line.

The user-agent stylesheet is set this way because without a `<!DOCTYPE>` declared, the browser is rendering in Quirks mode, which has a different default stylesheet than the normal Strict mode which is present when a `<!DOCTYPE>` is declared.