# flexbox with height: 100% doesn't work on chrome 72+

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Check the snippet bellow.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


.flex {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.holder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: initial !important;
    flex: 1;
}

.wrapper {

    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="flex"><!---->
        <nav style="height: 40px; background-color: blue"></nav>
        <!---->
        <div class="holder body">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <div class="holder">

                        <div>
                            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br>v
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="height: 60px; background-color: red"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you run this on chrome 71-, snippet above doesn't have body scroll, only `.wrapper` is scrollable. But the same page on chrome 72+ has the body scroll.

**EDIT**
Origin question has also issues with [quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode). Meaning without `<!doctype html>` this issue worked ok even on chrome 72+.

Comment: In the snippet I see the body having the scroll

Comment: @TemaniAfif I added update 1

Comment: ok, doctype issue, let me get the duplicate

Comment: you need to declare the HTML5 doctype which is done automatically using snippet here.

Comment: Hm... I want to remove the scroll from the body and move it to `.wrapper`. It seems like I need to **remove** the doctype. Is there anything else I can do to make snippet work with doctype?

Comment: wrapper is already having the scroll if you run the snippet full page but on small screen the content is overflowing and you have a body scroll

Comment: looking to it more closely both the snippet and the static page are the same ... if you add doctype you see any difference? this is probably a bug rather than a doctype issue

Comment: This is weird, I'm using chrome 72 on windows and this snippet shows me body scroll. [Here's the proof](https://imgur.com/a/zW5X2sn)

Comment: this is probably a bug then, will reopen the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif I needed to add `min-height` on .`holder` for chrome v72+ (with quirks mode). On lowest version this wasn't required.

Comment: ok then, it's this duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333 ... check at the end to see the note about different behavior, it seems changed now in the V72

Comment: I don't see this as reproducible on latest version of Chrom 73.x, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On chrome 72+ you need to set min-height on `.holder`. This is not required on versions before 72.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}


.flex {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.holder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: initial !important;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 0;
}

.wrapper {

    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="flex"><!---->
        <nav style="height: 40px; background-color: blue"></nav>
        <!---->
        <div class="holder body">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div>
                    <div class="holder">

                        <div>
                            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>v<br><br>v
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>


            </div>
            <div>
                <div style="height: 60px; background-color: red"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know if there's any documentation about this Chrome 72 change? Or a Chrome bug? I took a look, and I didn't see this mentioned in the changes to Chrome 72.

Comment: I see this Chromium bug
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927066
which refers to this discussion https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/alg8az/anyone_experiencing_issues_with_flexbox_and/