# TinyMCE doesn't work on all similar pages

Tags: tinymce

I have the TinyMCE sample with API key installed on a test page at https://myezwb.com/tinymce.htm - there is no other code on the page and the TinyMCE works great.

Now I have installed that same  at the top of 3 production pages at https://myezwb.com, just like I did on the test page.

It works on one page that has a single textarea but on similar pages with one or multiple textareas it won't work, with or without an API key.

I don't find any differences between the code or structure on the three pages and/or the test page.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors (if any) appear on the browser's console?

Comment: tinymce.min.js:2 Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode. TinyMCE requires standards mod. I'm not sure what that means as the script is exactly the same as in the ones that work.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
tinymce.min.js:2 Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode.
TinyMCE requires standards mode
```

explains the issue.  TinyMCE 5 requires the page in which it is loaded to be in Standards mode and not Quirks mode.

For more on this topic you can find lots of details online such as:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode
- https://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html
- [What is quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode)