# jQuery: Is there a way to maximize a Jquery UI Dialog to the browser size?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to maximize a Jquery UI Dialog to the browser size (max width / height)?

**Update:**

I am using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474009/browser-size-width-and-height) to get the height and width of the browser, and setting the height and the width properties of the Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looking at the manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), there are `height`, `width`, `maxHeight`, `maxWidth` properties you will need to use. To resize it to whatever browser window size is, you will have to use the `resize` event which van be seen by clicking on the `events` tab on the manual.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isFullScreen = false;

function toggleFullScreen() {

    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var windowH = $(window).height();

    if (!isFullScreen) {

        //view full screen mode
        var wFull = windowW - 100;
        var hFull = windowH - 100;

        var xLeft = parseInt((windowW / 2) - (wFull / 2));
        var yTop = parseInt((windowH / 2) - (hFull / 2));     

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dialog('option' , 'width', wFull);
            dialog.dialog('option' , 'height', hFull);    
            dialog.dialog('option', 'position', [xLeft,yTop]);
        }

        isFullScreen = true;

    } else {

        //view normal/original size mode
        //use the "dafault" height and width
        var xLeft = parseInt((windowW / 2) - (300 / 2));
        var yTop = parseInt((windowH / 2) - (200 / 2));

        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dialog('option' , 'width', 300);
            dialog.dialog('option' , 'height', 200);    
            dialog.dialog('option', 'position', [xLeft,yTop]);
        }

        isFullScreen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but full-screen will not work when the screen size can change. This happens, for instance, when you change the orientation of a tablet. Would it be possible to then resize the dialog?