# How to detect browser size using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am using the below code in one of my pages to help me work on a site to make it responsive:

```
document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);
```

The only problem is I don't wan't it showing my screen resolution size, I want it to show the browser size.

I.E, so it changes when I shrink the browser.

Comment: use `.resize()` of jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474211/1081079

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var width = $(this).width();
   var height = $(this).height();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`.

Check the below link, hopefully it will help you understand the logic:

http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/