# Android browser : getting size of viewport

Tags: javascript, android, viewport, android-browser

I am creating a overlay for websites which will access on mobile, In iPhone i'm getting visual viewport size by window.innerWidth and layout viewport size by document.documentElement.clientWidth in iPhone it is working perfectly but in android(2.2, 2.3.3) default browsers it is not giving a proper visual viewport size, and this size is not getting changed when I zoomed in or zoomed out.

so which js property do I need to use for getting proper visual viewport size, when I zoom in or zoom out.

Answer (score 1):

This option is supported starting from WebKit version 534.13. 
So only Android 3 browsers and above will supply visual viewport size, as lower Android versions are using WebKit 533.1.

Answer (score 0):

Android stock browser 4.0.3 and 4.1.2 looks like same issue. It seems it doesn't work properly for these browsers. It doesn't work even in chrome. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035211/2846477) is working example.