# Is there a webkit or IE equivalent of Firefox's window.mozInnerScreenY property?

Tags: browser, screen

The nice thing about the [FF property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozInnerScreenY) is that it works from within a cross-domain iframe. Anything like that available for chrome/safari?

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no native methods or properties to do this IIRC. Maybe give this a try?

[Find the exact height and width of the viewport in a cross-browser way (no Prototype/jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto)