# How can I get an iframe or window viewport size using just pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, doctype

I'm looking for a cross-browser and cross-site (any doctype) method for obtaining the viewport size.
I know that you can use `document.documentElement.clientHeight/Width` or `document.body.clientHeight/Width`, but they seem to depend on the doctype.

Please note this question refers to pure js only.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto

Comment: Just saw it does indeed supports iframes. Sorry.