# Screen resolution of visitor

Tags: c#, asp.net, resolution, monitor

I need to get the screen resolution of your visitors on the site. Is it possible to do this in ASP.NET? I get the screen resolution using the code:

```
var mn = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
int h = mn.Height;
int w = mn.Width;
```

But this resolution on the server. I need a resolution of client monitor.

Comment: Why do you need this information? Websites should work at any resolution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the exact height and width of the viewport in a cross-browser way (no Prototype/jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto)

Comment: You are most likely going to have to do it with client side code like JavaScript, even then you will only get the resolution of their browser window.

Comment: CSS media queries have become the accepted method for dealing with display resolution in a web app. See e.g. http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries

Comment: I need to get the value in the controller!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use javascript to accomplish this.[availHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen.availHeight) [availWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen.availWidth)

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

Then you will have to pass this back to your application somehow.

Comment: I need to get the value in the controller!

Comment: You can't from within the controller. You will need to get it via JavaScript then post it back to your controller with an ajax call or something.