# calling javascript function checking media

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a media query css block for the ipad

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
}
```

and for laptop and desktops
@media only screen 
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    }

I have a js function which needs to have different parameters depending upon which device I am on. So lets say something like this

```
if(@media only screen && (min-width : 1224px)){
    function operation(){
       var x = 2;
    }
}




if(@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)){
        function operation(){
           var x = 7;
        }
    }
```

Conceptually thats what I am trying to achieve which is definitely incorrect syntactically

Any help will be highly appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. The code you wrote is syntactically wrong. I hope the code below will help you.

```
if (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 1224px)').matches) {
   function operation(){
      var x = 2;
   }

} 

if(window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)').matches) {
     function operation(){
       var x = 7;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it works behind the scenes (and right now I'm to lazy to find out) but the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)-library has a method called [Modernizr.mq(string)](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) that will evaluate a media query and return a boolean.

It could be used like this (assuming modernizr is loaded and has the mq-method available).

```
if(Modernizr.mq('@media only screen && (min-width : 1224px)')) {
  function operation(){
    var x = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is good but I rather not use modernizer for just a small thing. Its another inclusion. But this is really good

Comment: The code is available at Github so you might still want to check it out if you want to support older browsers as well. It has some nifty fallbacks (and also checks for the prefixed version of matchMedia from Microsoft). https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/src/testMediaQuery.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following syntax

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
         var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 480px)");
         if (matchMedia('all and ').mql) {
                function operation(){
                   var x = 2;
                }
            }

            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto) answer to achieve what you want, like this:

```
var viewportDimensions = getViewport(), viewportWidth = viewportDimensions[0], viewportHeight = viewportDimensions[1];
if(viewportWidth > 1224)
{
   function operation(){
       var x = 2;
    }
}
if(viewportWidth > 768 && viewportWidth < 1024)
{
   function operation(){
       var x = 2;
    }
}
```

This method works on all browsers and doesn't need any external library dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the width of the window instead?

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth > 1224px){
    function operation(){
      var x = 2;
    }
}

if(windowWidth > 768px) && windowWidth < 1024px){
    function operation(){
       var x = 7;
    }
}
```