# Javascript: Can I use devicePixelRatio to compute device viewport size?

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

I try to use javascript to get mobile device viewport size, here I found some nice answer on the stackoverflow:

- [Find the exact height and width of the viewport in a cross-browser way (no Prototype/jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto)
- [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

They both recommend using `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` to get viewport size like this:

```
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
```

But I found this way sometime can not be accurate, when the device's browser have tool bar or address bar. So I figure out a way using `devicePixelRatio` to get mobile device viewport size:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio) {
    var physicsWidth = window.screen.width;
    var physicsHeight = window.screen.height;

    var viewportWidth = physicsWidth / window.devicePixelRatio;
    var viewportHeight = physicsHeight / window.devicePixelRatio;
}
```

Is this way OK to get viewport size?

Comment: What are you trying to do using these values?