# Bootstrap reorder left to right and right to left then break right to new line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

Given I have this snippet

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="left" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5">
          How are you?
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
          Thanks, I'm fine.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If open on browser it should display

```
How are you? Thanks, I'm fine.
```

When browser is reduced to less than 768px I want the above snippet to yield

```
Thanks, I'm fine.
How are you?
```

I am using the following javascript to detect when viewport width of browser is <=767.

```
 /*
  @Leo
  Obtained from: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766861/find-the-exact-height-and-width-of-the-viewport-in-a-cross-browser-way-no-proto
*/

var getviewport = function(){

    var viewPortWidth;
    var viewPortHeight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth,
        viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
    && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
    'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

     // older versions of IE
    else {
        viewPortWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewPortHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }
    return [viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight];
};

var adjust = function(){
    var width = getviewport()[0];

    if(width<=767){
        $("#left").addClass("col-xs-push-7");
        $("#right").addClass("col-xs-pull-5");
    }
    else{
        $("#left").removeClass("col-xs-push-7");
        $("#right").removeClass("col-xs-pull-5");       }
};
adjust();
$(window).resize(adjust);
```

So when the viewport width is <=767. I try to order the statement

```
"How are you? Thanks, I'm fine." to  "Thanks, I'm fine. How are you?
```

By adding corresponding xs-push-* and xs-pull-* I was able to achieve the above ordering to "Thanks, I'm fine. How are you?"

However, I feel something can be further done to break the statement to

```
Thanks, I'm fine.
How are you?
```

I will be glad if someone can offer help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can actually do this entirely with Bootstrap, no js needed!

To style the way it looks below the 768px breakpoint, just use `col-xs-`. To style the way it looks above 768, use `col-sm-`. You can't swap the order of the stacked columns (it'll always be the order they appear in the same order as in the markup), but you can use **push** and **pull** to change the order above the 768 breakpoint.

1. In the markup, order your columns the way you want them to appear when stacked
2. Add your `xs` classes - I'm not sure I understand what you want, but I think `.col-xs-10.col-xs-offset-1`
3. Add your "bigger-than-`xs`" classes. So `.col-sm-5` and `.col-sm-7`, remove the offsets with `.col-sm-offset-0`, and then switch the order by pushing the one column and pulling the other

Here's a working snippet. View it full-window to see how it works above 768. The result will look like this:

Wide (Bootstrap `sm` and above):
[image]

Narrow (Bootstrap `xs`):
[image]

(The pink area is just to show that the stacked columns are centered `col-10`)

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';

/* all of this just for demo purposes */
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.container {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
}
.row div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}
.row div:first-child {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7 col-sm-offset-0"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 col-sm-offset-0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. i want it to behave like this, for example if 1-2 is inline on the same row as left side and right side, I want the right which is 2 to come first and occupy a row and the left which is 1 to go to new line and occupy a row of its own. 1 - 2 before but becomes 2 \n 1

Comment: That's what this solution does :) you can see it if you click "expand snippet", then "run", then change your window size

Comment: it's almost working. Please do it to work like this, when I "expand snippet" then run let it show 2 - 1 instead of 1 - 2, then when i reduce the browser to less than 768px let it be 1 \n 2.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding. It sounds like now you're talking about just changing the text content? You can make that whatever you want, it doesn't change the layout. I just used those numbers so that you can see the order changing. If that's wrong, try to explain again

Comment: sorry, i've edited the question, you will understand me now.. thanks

Comment: I think you're getting tricked by the fact that I used numbers for the cell contents. It doesn't matter which one is called 1 and which one is called 2 - those numbers were just there to help you see that the order changes. I've edited my answer to use "blue" and "green" instead - maybe that will be more clear

Comment: we are almost getting it. The expected behavior is that when I Expand script and run, it should display blue green, don't do the ordering to green blue. ordering occurs when viewport width is less than 768px, so when viewport width <=767 do ordering to green blue then finally should appear green centered col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1  \newline blue centered by col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1

Comment: Is this what you want? >= 768: `• º`. < 768: `º \n •`

Comment: I've re-edited the question and explained in further details. I know your solution is not too far from the answer, me too i'm playing with it to get it work.

Comment: That's what this solution does :) I've added screenshots

Comment: WOW, thanks you are right. it works, i was having an error that interrupts Bootstrap.