# JavaScript - Get Browser Height

Tags: javascript, window, height

I am looking for a code snippet to get the height of the viewable area within a browser window.

I had this code, however it is somewhat bugged as if the the body doesn't exceed the height the of the window then it comes back short.

```
document.body.clientHeight;
```

I have tried a couple of other things but they either return NaN or the same height as the above.

Does anyone know how to get the real height of the browsing window?

Comment: Check [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript).

Answer (score 81):

You'll want something like this, taken from http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

```
function alertSize() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  window.alert( 'Width = ' + myWidth );
  window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
}
```

So that's `innerHeight` for modern browsers, `documentElement.clientHeight` for IE, `body.clientHeight` for deprecated/quirks.

Answer (score 48):

Try using jquery:

```
window_size = $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `window.innerHeight`

Comment: We don't need to support Internet Explorer :)

If you must, try document.documentElement.clientHeight or using jquery instead.

Answer (score 21):

The way that I like to do it is like this with a ternary assignment.

```
 var width = isNaN(window.innerWidth) ? window.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
 var height = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;
```

I might point out that, if you run this in the global context that from that point on you could use window.height and window.width.

Works on IE and other browsers as far as I know (I have only tested it on IE11).

Super clean and, if I am not mistaken, efficient.

Comment: I'm interested to know if there is a technical reason why the pattern `var width = window.innerWidth || window.clientWidth;` is not used.

Comment: Well the first reason is that only one of the two properties is defined, depending on the browser type used. As for why not just use the coalesce operator, technically that should be used when the items are defined, but one of them might be some false value. Chrome is smart enough to still give a value, but at least historically, Firefox would complain that the first variable doesn't exist. Not sure how it is now, but that's the reason why.

Comment: Ok, just for reference, I tested this in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE Edge. Using coalesce on undefined variables works fine, so it looks like that issue has been fixed. So with that in mind, the only reason you would prefer using ternary statements over the coalesce form is for personal style reasons, or so you can support older browsers. Keep in mind that when this andwer was written, we had to support IE6 and FF3, and if I had to guess, I would say it was FF3 that had the issue with the coalesce syntax.

Answer (score 4):

This should works too. First create an absolute `<div>` element with absolute position and 100% height:

```
<div id="h" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;"></div>
```

Then, get the window height from that element via `offsetHeight`

```
var winHeight = document.getElementById('h').offsetHeight;
```

---

**Update:**

```
function getBrowserSize() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.left = 0;
    div.style.width = '100%';
    div.style.height = '100%';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    var results = {
        width: div.offsetWidth,
        height: div.offsetHeight
    };
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div); // remove the `div`
    return results;
}

console.log(getBrowserSize());
```

Comment: @stuartdotnet You can always remove the DOM after get the height.

Answer (score 4):

There's a simpler way than a whole bunch of if statements. Use the or (||) operator.

```
function getBrowserDimensions() {
  return {
    width: (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth),
    height: (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight)
  };
}

var browser_dims = getBrowserDimensions();

alert("Width = " + browser_dims.width + "\nHeight = " + browser_dims.height);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var winWidth = window.screen.width;
var winHeight = window.screen.height;

document.write(winWidth, winHeight);
```

Comment: Its best to include some explanation of your answer along with any code, to give context to any future visitors to this question

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you can try this `$(window).innerHeight()` (Works for me on Chrome, FF and IE). With bootstrap modal I used something like the following;

```
$('#YourModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal-body').css('height', $(window).innerHeight() * 0.7);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the way I just figured out... No JS... 100% HTML & CSS:

(Will center it perfectly in the middle, regardless of the content size.

**HTML FILE**

```
<html><head>
<link href="jane.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="container">
<tr>
<td id="centerpiece">
123
</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

**CSS FILE**

```
#container{
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#centerpiece{
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

for centering images / div's held within the td, you may wish to try margin:auto; and specify a div dimension instead. -Though, saying that... the 'text-align' property will align much more than just a simple text element.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript version in case if jQuery is not an option:

```
window.screen.availHeight
```