# setting height properties

Tags: html, css, height

take two here. This problem has been paining me for a while.
I have a desired layout, similar to this;

```
<body>
<div id="first section">
<div id="second section">
<div id="third section">
<div id="fourth section">
<body>
```

Essentially what i am aiming for (in basic terms) is a layout that is 400% height, with each 'section', so to speak, taking up 100% height of ALL different sized screens. I have played around alot with mix,max and height properties to no avail, including setting the body's height to 100% with each 'section' being 25% of that...

Is this possible to do with basic css or am i looking at something more technical?

Comment: One problem is that you are not closing your `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are going to need to do this by setting the `DIV` element's height based on the [browser window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333329/javascript-get-browser-height) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Lemme say some suggestions.

1. You don't have a closing tag for the `div`, which might inherit the styles. So close the `div`s.
2. You need to close your `<body>` using `</body>`.
3. There is no parent `div` for wrapping up the elements. If you want the document to have something like a single screen with the whole contents in accordion, you can do this by giving a fixed height and positioning the inner `div`s. But I prefer you to do the same in `UL` and `LI`.

So, a solution for your question may be like this. Have this layout...

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="first section"></div>
        <div id="second section"></div>
        <div id="third section"></div>
        <div id="fourth section"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, you need to give a `height` for the `.wrap`, usually the screen's height. Now, the same screen's height should be given to the sections too. Keep the sections, positioned relatively and give `overflow: hidden;` to the wrap `div`.

```
.wrap {height: 100px /* just for here */; overflow: hidden;}
.wrap .section {height: 100px /* just for here */; position: relative;}
```

Now, when you want to show the first page, use this way:

```
.first {top: 0;}
```

Or, you can do even this way.

```
.section {display: none;}
.first.section {display: block;}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/u2R28/) for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of pointers:

- Your closing `body` tag is wrong, should be `</body>`
- Your `div` tags aren't closed.
- You're using the `id` attribute as if it were `class`.

If I understood your question correctly, the sections should not overlap.

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7kJk/) out and see if it's what you're looking for.

#### The Code

**Markup:**

```
<div class="first section">First section</div>
<div class="second section">Second section</div>
<div class="third section">Third section</div>
<div class="fourth section">Fourth section</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Mate, i could bloody kiss you. Worked a treat, such a simple resolution. You're a bloody legend!!

Comment: My pleasure, I think I'll have to take a rain check though. Please consider accepting this as the solution if it worked for you.