# Setting a fixed height and width for a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function scrollfun()
{
    var ob = document.getElementById('rowScroll');
    ob.style.height ="300px";
    ob.style.width = "200px";               
}
```

Here `rowScroll` is the `<div>` id. The above code is working properly. But the following code is not working:

```
function scrollfun()
{
    var ob = document.getElementById('rowScroll');
    ob.style.height ="30%";
    ob.style.width = "20%";             
}
```

How can I get this working with percentages?

Comment: Percents work the same way as do px work.

Comment: *'Not working'* doesn't say anything about the problem; in general, explain what you are expecting to happen, and what is actually happening. In this case, the latter is probably sufficient.

Comment: can I ask why you are doing this with a JS function and not using CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a div tag to achieve this. See the working code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayResult()
{
document.getElementById("b1").style.height="200%";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height:25px;">
<input type="button" id="b1" onclick="displayResult()" value="Change height of button" >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you "tell" it what are these percentages from. like

```
function scrollfun()
{
    var ob = document.getElementById('rowScroll');
    ob.style.height = (container-width * 30)/100 + "px"
    ob.style.width = (container-width * 20)/100 + "px"             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI percentage based width height depends upon parent container of your element 'rowScroll'. Try giving height, width info to the parent itself...

UPDATE:

for making height width 50% of screen following will do:

```
function windowHW() {
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 4 compatible
    myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
  return [myHeight,myWidth];
}
function scrollfun()
    {
        var ob = document.getElementById('rowScroll');
        document_dimension = windowHW();
        ob.style.height =document_dimension[0]/2;
        ob.style.width =document_dimension[1]/2;
    }
```

Please note that function windowHW is slight modification of solution given in:

[stackoverflow question: JavaScript - Get Browser Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333329/javascript-get-browser-height)  answered by [meder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145190/meder)

Comment: height of the div should be 50% or 60% of height of the screen or window

Comment: This is not an answer. To request additional information or suggest a modification, post a *comment* below the original post. The *Answer* section, is reserved for answers (or at least attempts to answer) the problem posed in the question.

Comment: i kept that as an answer : 'percentage based width height depends upon parent container of your element 'rowScroll'. Try giving height, width info to the parent itself.'

Answer (score 0):

just use the property `className` from javascript

```
function scrollfun()
{
   document.getElementById("rowScroll").className = "MyClass";      
}
```

And in your css

```
.MyClass{height:30%;width:20%;}
```

Comment: there's no difference betweem doing this and what he is doing

Comment: You can target an element using its ID, no need to add a class. `#rowScroll{height:30%; width:20%;}`

Comment: @HeHui : Doing it with the support of CSS, Because of OP can't achieve with the values using javascript