# How to use properties in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

```
"Window": {
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
},
"Label": {
    font: {
        fontSize: 32,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
},
"Button": {
    width: '50%',
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
},
".button": {
    randomProp: 'OK',
    top: window.height * somevalue;
}
```

How can i use my `Window's Height` to set to my `button's` top.

Comment: it seems you are going about things possibly the long way round, please explain what you are trying to achieve and possible use an example site or image.

Comment: Strangest looking CSS I ever saw.

Answer (score 0):

You can access styling properties of an object through the `.style` attribute of the object. I.e:

```
mybutton.style.top = "10px";
```

Getting the windows current hight is trickier in pure JS, but the jQuery library does it with ease:

```
$( 'window' ).height();
```

If you don't want to use jQuery then here is how to do it with just JS: [JavaScript - Get Browser Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333329/javascript-get-browser-height)

If your intent is achievable with just CSS and percent values that is the best way to go, but I assume you are trying to attach something that is going to float relative to window size, like a footer that is always in the bottom, which without some of the new CSS3 selectors can be a pain in CSS and probably should be solved in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript for this.

You can use `position: absolute;` to set the position of your `button` relative to the viewport.

```
button {position: absolute; top: %/px;}
```

[Here is your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNFgX/).