# How to calculate the actual screen distance jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to place an Ad in a page column. When I scroll down, I want the Ad to follow all the way, but position in the vertical middle of the page. Using the *script* right now can only set a certain distance but cannot set exact 50% distance.

I have tired `$window.height()/2` or `$document.height()/2`, but they calculate my Table height instead of the actual screen height. How to solve this? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function () {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > $window.height() / 2) {

        $sidebar.css('position', 'absolute');
        $sidebar.css('top', $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() / 2);
        $sidebar.slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $sidebar.css('position', 'auto');
        $sidebar.css('top', 'auto');
    }
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<br><br>
<table bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="800" height="3000" align="center" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="150" valign="top">
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:white;"></div>
<br>
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:blue;"></div>
<br>
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:yellow;"></div>
<br>
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:pink;"></div>
<br>
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:maroon;"></div>
<br>
<!-- AD -->
<div style="width:100px;height:100;background:red;" id="sidebar">test</div>

<br>

</td>
<td width="500"></td>
<td width="150"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jquery document, `$(window).height();` should return height of browser viewport.

I represent the demo based on your html and js. It looks like your site now :)

see it: http://jsfiddle.net/FrFsP/1/

Comment: Nice one I think this is what he wants to achieve  .. @IamRan

Comment: Hmmm it's close but not exactly... Can you check this website? http://live1.7m.cn/ The Ad in the middle column will stack in place at first, only when scroll over, it will stay in the middle of the page. Btw, I copied your scripts and tested and found it only work on IE but not on chrome...

Comment: it's weird, I am using chrome, I wrote the demo using chrome... I will visit the site and take a try.

Comment: Thank you dear. But still only work on IE, chrome not working... what script should I call for this code? Is this one okay? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Answer (score 1):

Try `screen.height` to get actual height. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_height.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need `window.innerHeight` to get the real dimensions (for modern browsers). Take a look at [JavaScript - Get Browser Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333329/javascript-get-browser-height) for a small wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the idea right, I think [this is what you are looking for](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/)
just check out [this example](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-3.html) to see if this is it

If it's not what you are looking for, please can you clarify a little more?

Comment: hmm seems not, please kindly check this site and see. http://live1.7m.cn/pk_live_ft.aspx?view=odds&match=&line=no

Comment: I mean the 3 small Ad inside the column of the page, when it scroll down it will locate at the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

As documented here: http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
$("div.target:nth-child(1)").center(true);
$("div.target:nth-child(2)").center(false);
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/GbDw9/2886/)

Comment: no matter I change the parameters to outerheight or innerheight or screen.height, it's still calculating the height of my table. I scroll over the red box is move the the 1/2 height of my table instead of middle of the screen. Should I make some change in the HTML instead?