# Scrolling to top with offset depending on size of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that my scroll function is not scrolling properly on different screen resolutions. Problem is coming from the `offset`. Is there any way to have `offset` in percents?  I've tried -10% for example but it didn't worked.

```
$(".scrollto_home").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var defaultAnchorOffset = 0;

    var anchor = $('#home').attr('data-attr-scroll');

    var anchorOffset = $('#home').attr('data-scroll-offset');
    if (!anchorOffset)
        anchorOffset = defaultAnchorOffset;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#home').offset().top - 100 - anchorOffset
    }, 500);
});
```

The problem is that the scroll is going too far when going up on smaller resolutions that 1920x1080

Comment: Get a percentage of the screen size and then subtract it. To get literally the screen: `screen.height` to get the browser height: `window.innerHeight` but you might want to refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333336/10315665). Or did I get your question wrong?

Comment: You get it right sir! I have a problem with calculating it and putting it into the script, tried many times

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way. Using timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('html body').animate({
     scrollTop: $('#home')[0].scrollHeight
         },400);
},600);
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that the scroll is going too far when going up on smaller resolutions that 1920x1080

Comment: generally it scroll with your screen height. Then you need to define your screen size as you want to scroll

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you want to scroll 10% (of the screen height) below/above the anchor. You simply set the offset like:

```
let percentage = 10;
let offset = window.innerHeight / 100 * percentage;
```

and then add or subtract that offset depending if you want to scroll above or below it.

To get good browser compatibility when getting the screen height, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333336/10315665).

*Note: I'm not that used to jQuery so tell me if I'm missing something*

***Note2:*** If you're having problems with your jQuery, please consider creating a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so I can test out stuff ^^ :)