# How to find the screen real estate of a mobile device?

Tags: php, jquery, mobile-website, dimensions

I'm planing to develop mobile version for my website, I need to consider all the devices like with different screen dimensions. I tried to find out a way to get the real estate width of mobile devise to shoe my mobile site accordingly, can anybody please suggest a solution for this problem. I'll be very happy if I got some solution to this problem using jQuery or PHP because I'm using these to develop my mobile website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the browser viewport dimensions with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

Comment: @Dan: jQuery width() and height() functions are not giving correct values for mobile devises. I want to know the exact dimensions of devise screen from which user is accessing my website but not the window sizes. Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using JavaScript, use CSS3 media queries to target different screen sizes, for example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" />
```

**Update:** If really necessary, use `screen.width` and `screen.height` to access the width and height of the screen.

[W3C CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: thanks yuxhuang, actually I want to find out the exact dimensions of of the devise screen from which user is accessing my website. Do you know how to get those dimensions?

Comment: code added in to include JavaScript access to the width and height.