# Getting height of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm building a dialog whose content is an iframe. When the dialog opens I have the following code that I pulled from various sources in attempting to make this work:

```
var iframeDOM = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
iframeDOM.setAttribute("frameborder", "0"); 
iframeDOM.setAttribute("scrolling", plugin.settings.scrolling ? "" : "no"); 
iframeDOM.setAttribute("allowtransparency", isIE ? "true" : ""); 



var setDimensions = function(){
                        console.log("load");
                        var iframeWin = iframeDOM.contentWindow || iframeDOM.contentDocument.parentWindow;
                        if (iframeWin.document.body) {
                            console.log("new height: " + iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight); //Not giving real height, always 0
                            console.log("new client height: " + iframeWin.document.documentElement.clientHeight); 
                            iframeDOM.height = 550;
                            iframeDOM.width  = 550;
                        }

                    };

                    $(iframeDOM).load(setDimensions)
                                .appendTo($element.children().first())
                                .attr({ src: plugin.settings.href, name: new Date().getTime() });
```

As you can see I was attempting to log the height of the iFrame but it always prints 0 (as temporary workaround I'm setting the dimensions statically)

EDIT: Another solution which I've updated this OP with returns the error:

```
 Error: Permission denied to access property 'document' if (iframeWin.document.body) {
```

Comment: Maybe help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087278/how-to-get-the-height-of-an-iframe-with-javascript-from-inside-the-iframe-what

Comment: I just tried clientHeight , which I added to OP , and also returns 0 :(

Comment: Check also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846132/jquery-get-height-of-iframe-content-when-loaded

Comment: @FaceOfJock for that answer I get Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

if (iframeWin.document.body) { ... I updated OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframe does not automatically take height and width. You need to define it manually, hence it is only possible through javascript to catch the actual height of page loading into iframe and assign it as a height for iframe. But this approach will create instability.

UPDATE

calculate the height of page using .height() function and assign it to the iframe. It will work this way.

Comment: I'm doing it through javascript as you can see. Why do you say it will create instability?

Comment: It will first load your iframe with default values for height and width, then it will load the page and calculate the height of that page and then assign back to your iframe which will result in dancing iframe.

Comment: That's ok, it's hidden at first and I show it after assigning dimensions. Unfortunately I don't see another way as it's currently loading into a tiny area and clipping the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I found that works pretty good. I think it needs tweaking but I'm not good with JavaScript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
  var newheight;
  var newwidth;

if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
}

document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>

<iframe name="content" src="http://my-domain.com/home.html" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');">
</iframe>
```