# Is it possible to detect the viewport/window width with Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I've found that using the `Modernizr.mq()` function to check media queries is a much more accurate way to run Javascript based on the viewport width, because it matches up with my CSS.

However, is it possible to get a width value from Modernizr?

Answer (score 3):

Using built-in tests, nope, that's not possible. At least, there are no mentions in the [Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/).

However, you don't need Modernizr to get the dimensions of your browser. You can do it by using plain javascript:

```
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/2083599)

Comment: JavaScript and jQuery methods are of no use. On iPad devices, I have witnessed them always failing in one case or another.