# hiding select menu and opening with a button

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

Hey guys im on my mobile trying to use jsbin and what a pain. Anyways is there a way to hide a select menu and on click of a button open the select menu and since mobile devices shows a popup box id want this for my navigation for mobiles (responsive)

My submenus just dont work with the ux and ui with the mobile responsive layout so I was thinking of using a select menu and those things are ugly so wanted your opinion on how to achieve this if at all possible.  Ive tried this http://jsbin.com/narigudu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is a fairly broad question and normally I'd vote to close it -- but I'm going to try to give you some usable pointers.

You have a few options at your disposal and they all have their pros and cons.

## Media Queries [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

This is the "stock answer" to these kinds of questions.  Put both the drop down list *and* the  button to pop up the list.  Use media query to check screen resolution and hide/unhide the proper one.

## JavaScript viewport detection [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

This one is a little trickier since you have to also sit on the `windowl.resize` event for those pesky people who rotate their phones.  Make sure you are getting the *viewport* and not the screen.

## Device Detection [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Um.. don't.  Really.  Device detection is bad and lists go stale.  MUCH better to use the other methods and really, media queries are the right solution to this.

Comment: No I know how to make it responsive. This is my issue for the responsive size for mobile devices `(max-width:320px)` I want my nav bar buttons to click and open a select that is hidden... hope you understand