# How to get viewport height of screen of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All questions I see answer:

```
$(window).height();
```

But this returns not the size of viewport but size of page, for example if I style `<body>` to height 1000px this will return 1000 but not the size of view port. I need size of viewport not the collective page size that is scroll able.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript

Comment: NO `Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)` is also outputting height of page size i.e. 1000 that is way larger than viewport.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
if(window.innerWidth !== undefined && window.innerHeight !== undefined) {
var w=window.innerWidth;
var h=window.innerHeight;
} else {
var w=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var h=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
var txt="Page size: width=" + w + ", height=" + h;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
<body onresize="myFunction()" onload="myFunction()">
<p>
Try to resize the page.
</p>
<p id="demo">
&nbsp;
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).height();
```

should return the height of the viewport (even if you set the height of the body tag in pixels). I also use:

```
var heightViewport = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

which has given me better accuracy on iOS especially.

```
$(document).height();
```

should return the height of the document (hence the height of the body tag in your case).

Are your sure you are not using document instead of window?

Answer (score 0):

It will return the size of the viewport.

```js
$('#viewportDimensions').text($(window).width() + ', ' + $(window).height());

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#viewportDimensions').text($(window).width() + ', ' + $(window).height());
});
```

[resize page in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88mrxnsu/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
var y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
    console.log(x,y);
```

main source:http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript