# window.innerWidth includes the scroll-bar width

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate the viewport's width, but **excluding the scroll-bar's width**. Someone on SO said `window.innerWidth` can do this, but it takes the scroll-bar into account.

I tried using `document.body.clientWidth` but when the window is horizontally scrolled, this fails.

**Even if `document.body.clientWidth > window.innerWidth`, I need to get the window's width, but without scroll-bar's width**

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript

Comment: It is exactly what I am doing, but more aesthetic

Comment: @Oriol,it is not duplicate, because there's not what I need. In that question, the OP is not interested in includin/excluding the scroll-bar's width/height, but I am!

Comment: @Victor Maybe true, but multiple answers address your problem.

Comment: Well, the scroll bar is part of the content, so it being taken into accout to the viewport is no mistake. You can try and style the scroll bar so you know exactly what its width is. There are some plugins to help with that, like iScroll.js, NiceScroll etc. that make a neat scroll similar to the iPhone, it hovers over the content and disappears when you are not scrolling or moving your mouse etc.

Comment: This one is nice too http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, `$(window).width()` will return what you want.

If your document has a horizontal scrollbar, `$(document).width()` will return the document width instead of the window width.

Using pure JavaScript, you can extract the document width from main window using `documentElement` with this code which works the same as the jQuery code above:

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Comment: How is this implemented in jQuery? I want to using jQuery

Comment: you can include jquery from Google or Microsoft then using **var mywidth=$(document).width()** will set what you want in "mywidth". This is how to implement jquery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Can this be done with out jQuery?

Comment: Yes. I have updated my answer by adding a pure JavaScript code. @fraxture