# getViewportHeight() resulting in only a piece of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code fragment in Javascript:

```
slider.viewport.height(getViewportHeight())
```

It resizes the height of a slider. I would like to resize to stay with 100px unless in bottom. I've tried using something like:

```
slider.viewport.height(getViewportHeight()-100px);
```

But it doesn't work.

What I need is that the slider to resize and occupies only a fixed height of the viewport with a spare in the bottom.

Comment: could you please add some more code and explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `getViewportHeight()` works.. then you just have to remove the `px` measures. After the math operation is completed, you add it.

```
slider.viewport.height((getViewportHeight()-100) + 'px');
```

In case your `getViewportHeight()` doesn't work, here you have some good ways to get your viewport height: [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)