# full window visualisation with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.js for a diagram. I want it to fill the whole window, no margin, no scrollbar, full height and full width. I don't necessary want it to be responsive.

Here is my  failed attempt :

CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

JS :

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

var svg = d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

HTML :

```
<body id="d3">    
    <script src="scripts/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

On chrome both toolbars are displayed (the generated SVG is actually slightly bigger than the body).

**Edit** : second attempt, works in chrome, height still incorrect in IE :

```
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
    height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
```

and :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(Credit to : [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript))

PS : this is pure madness

**2nd edit :** : window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight works (at least in chrome and ie11). If you are also banging your head against the wall note that **the element inspector report a wrong value for the height** ... I checked the height and width of the viewport with an image editor and they match with window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that your scrollbars move about the width/height of the scrollbars themselves.  Easy fix is:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ta42lNnjdUQOFn1tEGcn?p=preview).

Comment: this does hide the scrollbars, but the SVG is still taller than the body if you look at it with the element inspector.

Comment: forget about my previous comment, the element inspector report a wrong value for the height :(