# Making each section get the perfect height of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

Often I visit websites where the background-image fits perfectly into my viewport size. When you scroll.. the next section fits perfectly into the viewport too

As a reference use this [url](http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-one-a9/)

It does not matter whether I am using a 18' monitor or a 21' inch

Checking the source code I found this:

```
<section class="slide" style="height: 939px;"> .... </section>
<section class="slide" style="height: 939px;"> .... </section>
<section class="slide" style="height: 939px;"> .... </section>
```

Somehow they managed to capture my viewport height and adjust each section dynamically.

Is it right to assume that upon page load they perform some window.height and then dynamically set height of each section to that value or is there some utility that does this automatically ?

Comment: Not an answer, but that can be done with `100vh` easily.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. The height of the sections are mostly set using javascript.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript