# CSS for Multiple Fullscreen Rows w/ Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with the CSS to have 5 rows stacked on top of each other, and each row is 100% height and 100% width of the browser.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="1"></a>          
        <h1>section 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="2"></a>
        <h1>section 2</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="3"></a>          
        <h1>section 3</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="4"></a>          
        <h1>section 4</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="5"></a>          
        <h1>section 5</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
html,body { margin:0; padding:0; }
.fullscreen { height:100%; width:100%; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the problem here? Did you try using 100vh??

Comment: @ikeMiguel 100vh didn't work.  Heidel did a fiddle below where 100vh works, but it's not working in my code.  Wonder if it's Bootstrap that's causing 100vh not to work.

Comment: Did you add 100% to height and width for html and body?

Comment: What is row-fluid for?? Do you have the css for that? Instead of using row-fluid, you should use row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 100% for your height, you could use 100vh. `vh`is viewport height.

Your `.fullscreen` css should now be:

```
.fullscreen {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: 100vh isn't working.  Wonder if it's b/c of Bootstrap.

Comment: @s15199d instead of using row-fluid, you should use row only. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `viewport height` property to set height of each div equals screen height like `height: 100vh;`

```
.fullscreen { width:100%; height: 100vh; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/05w2bhoz/

You can read about it for example [here](http://stanhub.com/how-to-make-div-element-100-height-of-browser-window-using-css-only/) or just google it.
But unfortunately it's not cross-browser method, so if you need full support you should use js or jQuery to set height of each div equals window height. 
Read this [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

Comment: Saying its not cross-browser method is wrong, as all new browser can do this. Saying _some older ones_ would be okay though.

Comment: @Heidel thanks for the fiddle.  Your fiddle works, but it doesn't working when I plug your css into mine.  I wonder if Bootstrap is causing 100vh not to work.

Answer (score 1):

just replace the height:100% by 100vh

```
.fullscreen { height:100vh; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this may help you in your css

```
html, body
{
height: 100%;
}
 body 
{
min-height: 100%;
}
.fullscreen
{
height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See example maybe used for you: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nt2q13x/)

CSS:

```
html,body {margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%;}
#wrapper, .container-fluid, .fullscreen { height:100%; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
html,body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0; 
 padding:0;
 position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.fullscreen {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="1"></a>          
        <div class="span12"><h1>section 1</h1><span>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="2"></a>
        <div class="span12"><h1>section 2</h1><span>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="3"></a>          
        <div class="span12"><h1>section 3</h1><span>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="4"></a>          
        <div class="span12"><h1>section 4</h1><span>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid fullscreen"><a name="5"></a>          
        <div class="span12"><h1>section 5</h1><span>
    </div>

</div>
```