# Scroll to near the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, scroll

How do I scroll *near* the bottom of a page. I'm using the following code to scroll to the *very* bottom:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

How do I change this code to scroll *near* the bottom?

Comment: can you give us a reason on why you want *near* and not *exactly* the bottom? Because that may help a lot.

Comment: @Jhecht I'm making an endless content application. When the user scrolls to the bottom, more content loads. I want the user to be near the bottom when they scroll, but not load more content...

Comment: so you want for it to scroll to like... the last current item before loading more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How near?

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height() - 1000);
```

Will scroll close to the bottom. The problem here is that you have to consider the height of the viewport as well.

A good, cross browser way to [get the viewport height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript) is:

```
var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)
```

then:

```
var offset = 100;//your offset. 100px from the bottom here

$(document).scrollTop($(document).height() - (height + offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).scrollTop(($(document).height() - [the offset you want]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but the document height must be greater than the window height for this to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      var offset = 500;
      var scrollX = $(document).height() - offset;
      alert(scrollX);
      $(document).scrollTop(scrollX);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<p>lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum lorem Ipsum </p>

<button>Scroll to bottom</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The goal is to be *near*, but not *at* the bottom. I've already accomplished this code...

Comment: You can define offset value as in the updated snippet