# JavaScript calculate with viewport width/height

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I am trying to set a responsive point in my mobile Webview and did this:

```
var w = window.innerWidth-40;
var h = window.innerHeight-100;
```

This works great so far. But the values -40 and -100 are not in the viewport scaling height and width.

When I do this:

```
var w = window.innerWidth-40vw;
var h = window.innerHeight-100vh;
```

as it should be to stay responsive and relative to the viewport - the JS does not work anymore.
I think vh and vw works only in CSS ?
How can I achieve this in JS ?

Pleas no JQuery solutions - only JS!

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Based on [this site](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) you can use the following util functions to calculate your desired values as a function of a percent of screen width or height:

```js
function vh(percent) {
  var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
  return (percent * h) / 100;
}

function vw(percent) {
  var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  return (percent * w) / 100;
}

function vmin(percent) {
  return Math.min(vh(percent), vw(percent));
}

function vmax(percent) {
  return Math.max(vh(percent), vw(percent));
}

console.info(vh(20), Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0));
console.info(vw(30), Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0));
console.info(vmin(20));
console.info(vmax(20));
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/3819411) incredible question in my code!

Comment: This is awesome - thank you very much - I accept this nice solution

Comment: what is v argument that all function takes in?

Comment: The value that you want to convert into `vh` or `vw`

Comment: Careful! The vmin and vmax functions here don't work for negative numbers

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function getViewport() {

 var viewPortWidth;
 var viewPortHeight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
   viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth,
   viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
 && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewPortHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }

 // older versions of IE
 else {
   viewPortWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
   viewPortHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }
 return [viewPortWidth, viewPortHeight];
}
```

Reference: http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/

Comment: No issues. I just posted it so that you could choose between single function call and multiple calls according to your needs. Then again it always helps me to look up different answers.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that JS does not have `40vh`, calculate how much pixels is `40vh` first to use it. It will throw error when doing `1000 - 40vh`

`40vh` means `40 % of viewport height`. So `window.innerHeight * 0.4 == 40vh`

Also there is no such thing as `wh`, only `vh` (% of viewport height)

Comment: Should I calculate the pixels? This could work I guess.

Comment: @TobiasAlt Yes, it would work, just calculate everything in integers/floats

Comment: Your answer would be acceptable of course but above is a complete solution - I have to accept this one. But thank you I vote you up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, if you can fully edit the page, is to make a css class that has -40vw and -100vh like so:

CSS:

```
.class{
    width: -40vw;
    height: -100vh;
}
```

JS:

```
element.classList.add("class");
```

Note: "classList" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9. If you want it to work in all browsers, use this for JS instead:

```
function myFunction() {
    var element, name, arr;
    element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    name = "mystyle";
    arr = element.className.split(" ");
    if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
        element.className += " " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to surround it in quotes I think.
`var w = window.innerWidth = "40vw"
var w = window.innerWidth = "40vw"`

Answer (score 0):

this is my solve with you can use CSS;

```
    // calc dynamic customer device height/width
    let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01,
        vw = window.innerWidth * 0.01;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw', `${vw}px`);
```

How to use in CSS ?

If you will use **100vh** or **100vw** with this method, you should set 100vh/100vw for uncompatible browser.

Examples;

```
.wrapper{
    height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}

.slide-container{
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100 - var(--menuHeight) - var(--footerHeight));
}

.little-image{
    width: calc(var(--vw, 1vw) * 5);
    margin-bottom: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 1);
}

/* and more.. */
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a universal solution, but it's a much simpler implementation if you're working with a page that is always 100% displayed within the viewport (ie, if the body doesn't have to be scrolled and always matches the window width and height).

```
let vh = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

This sets the vh variable to the pixel value of the document body with just one line of code.

Useful for game dev and other scenarios where you have the body affixed to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

get `vmin` in px

```js
function vmin(){
    return window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth ? window.innerHeight: window.innerWidth;
}
```