# Follow mouse on hover using animate Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to **achieve [this](https://www.fredperry.com/reissues)** mousemove effect over the images.
The images seem like it's following my mouse,I'm trying to follow it and so far [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/r0nnvw3f/). I tried this example https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/SYwba/. But I'm stuck on combining it with my current fiddle.

This is my desired output.Like the images is following the mouse. [Output](https://www.fredperry.com/reissues)

```js
$('.animated').hover(
    function() {
        $('.animated').animate({
            marginTop:20
        });
    },
    function() {
        $('.animated').animate({
            marginTop:10
        });
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="animated" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
```

Also tried this:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.logo').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="logo" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" alt="Google">
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? The fred perry is moving left and right, yours up and down

Comment: @mplungjan like [this](https://www.fredperry.com/reissues) I'm trying to follow this style.

Comment: It is not clear what your code does not do.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry,My code animation is up and down only,I wanted to animate like similar to the example.Like its following the cursors movement.

Comment: you will have to do some ´.on("mousemove", function(e) {}´ and capture the mouse position

Comment: @Cheshire I did something like this,but it image is following the mouse all the way,Not like my desired ouput.It's just staying in there and not following it fully.

Comment: Is it a good question, hope someone with enough knowledge answer

Comment: @SilverSurfer Actually created a working example based on OP's code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is actually quite simple: what you want to do is to offset the image away from its original position based on the relative position of the cursor **in the document/viewport**. We will need to perform all this calculations in the `mousemove` event on document.

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {...});
```

Also, this means that you will need some following information:

1. determine the maximum offset you want the image to be moved from its original position
2. the viewport width and height
3. the mouse/cursor position **relative** to viewport height—that will give us a range of [0, 1]
4. transform that range to [-1, 1], since negative values are used to move to the top/left and positive values used to move to the bottom/right
5. use CSS3 transform to move the image

---

## Step-by-step guide

### 1. Determine maximum offset

Let's say we want to restrict the movement to ±30px. We can define them as:

```
// Maximum offset for image
var maxDeltaX = 30,
    maxDeltaY = 30;
```

### 2. Get viewport dimensions

Viewport dimensions can be accessed by [`document.documentElement.clientWidth/clientHeight`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript):

```
// Get viewport dimensions
var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

### 3 and 4. Get the *relative* position of the cursor to the viewport

The key here is to calculate the relative position of the cursor to the viewport. First, we get the fraction of the mouse/cursor coordinates to the viewport, which will give us a range of [0, 1]. However, we need to transform this into [-1, 1], so that we can calculate left/top movement (using negative values) and bottom/right movement (using positive values). The arithmetic transformation from [0, 1] to [-1, 1] is simply multiplying to 2 (so you get [0, 2]) and minus 1 (then you get [-1, 1]):

```
// Get relative mouse positions to viewport
var mouseX = e.pageX / viewportWidth * 2 - 1,
    mouseY = e.pageY / viewportHeight * 2 - 1;
```

### 5. Use CSS3 `transform` to position your image

This is the most straight forward part. The amount to translate is simply `mouseX` × `maxDeltaX` and the same along the y-axis. We pass these values into `transform: translate(<x>px, <y>px)`:

```
// Calculate how much to transform the image
var translateX = mouseX * maxDeltaX,
    translateY = mouseY * maxDeltaY;
$('.animated').css('transform', 'translate('+translateX+'px, '+translateY+'px)');
```

---

## Working example

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
// Settings
// Maximum offset for image
var maxDeltaX = 30,
    maxDeltaY = 30;

// Bind mousemove event to document
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {

  // Get viewport dimensions
  var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  // Get relative mouse positions to viewport
  // Original range: [0, 1]
  // Should be in the range of -1 to 1, since we want to move left/right
  // Transform by multipling by 2 and minus 1
  // Output range: [-1, 1]
  var mouseX = e.pageX / viewportWidth * 2 - 1,
      mouseY = e.pageY / viewportHeight * 2 - 1;
      
  // Calculate how much to transform the image
  var translateX = mouseX * maxDeltaX,
      translateY = mouseY * maxDeltaY;
  $('.animated').css('transform', 'translate('+translateX+'px, '+translateY+'px)');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="animated" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
```

Comment: how can I apply this using on hover? I want to do something like this one https://angle3.webflow.io/. I've tried .hover() but am not sure how to trigger the mousemove event.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding hover event to only div or  some container in which you want to move the image instead of image itself.

```
$('.wrapper-div').hover();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just give you a hint

```js
$('.animated').mousemove(
  function(ev) {
    document.getElementById("MouseCoord").innerHTML = ev.clientX + ':' + ev.clientY;
  }
);

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var rect = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();
  // .toFixed(0) only remove decimal part for a nice display
  document.getElementById("BoxSize").innerHTML = 
    "Box is at (" + rect.left.toFixed(0) + ";" + rect.top.toFixed(0) + ")" +
    " with size " + rect.width.toFixed(0) + "x" + rect.height.toFixed(0);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: .1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="MouseCoord">-</p>
<p id="BoxSize">-</p>
<div id="container">
  <img class="animated" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: similar to this one?https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mousemove

Comment: @rainalasa yes. Now you will need to compare your image containter position (centered) with mouse position, and move your image accordingly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/88526/3082/ i saw something like this,Its pretty close,Although its moving outside the div.

Comment: Its up to you to code the "do not overflow" behavior. I've added some hints to my answer, especially to get an element position and size

Comment: @rainalasa you can add `if/else` statements that gets the width of the moving box and compare if the position + width is bigger than the outsider box, then do nothing