# Check the div's height every 5 seconds and change class if true

Tags: javascript

I have this function already, which checks for change, and if true only updates this div.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            success: function(data) {
                var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
                $('div#vs').html(result);
            }
        })
    }, 5000); // refreshing after every 5000 milliseconds
})
```

This works great, but now I want to add another function, I have made this javascript http://jsfiddle.net/jockebq/ocLh1rLd/

What it does is that if the height of the div `#vs` exceeds `300px` it will add class `.vscroll` to `#vs`.
I have managed to make this work great in JSFiddle, but I cannot figure out how to merge this together with my javascript above.

I'm very much stuck, and I cannot find any information on how to do this. All help and tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure i am missing something here but why not just
add it inside the function passed to setInterval and run it alongside the ajax call

```
     var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                success: function(data) {
                    var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
                        $('div#vs').html(result);
                        if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight > 300 ) 
                            $('div#vs').addClass('vscroll');
                    }
            });


        }, 5000); // refreshing after every 5000 milliseconds
        })
```

PS: Your ajax better not be as you pasted it here!

EDIT: added the code in the success callback, since you probably want to resize when the new content is appended,as said by Pierre

Comment: I guess it would be better to place the `addClass` code at the end of the `success` callback code so it updates after the data is appended.

Comment: This is fantastic, helped me solve a big problem for me! Last thing is that i would like to do a percentage of the screen, instead of 300px. Is it possible to add percentage instead? Or maybe vw? So that it works with every resolution!

Comment: instead of 300 try getting the viewport height
var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
and then the percent that you want off of that H.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript