# How can I determine the exact value used for a media query?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

When using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I can use css

```
@media all and (min-width:400px) { ... }
```

or javascript

```
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches)
```

to style / build the page according to screen threshholds.

How can I determine the exact value of the width (other than narrowing it down via javascript)?

Some testing indicated that the value used is the same as in `screen.width`. Is that true? Under every circumstance?

Comment: According to the specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width) the width refers to the viewport. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/6041439 for determining the values with JS.

Comment: I don't think there's any other solution than javascript (jQuery): `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. `screen.width` is the width of the entire screen which may be bigger than the window.