# Angular: change service endpoint depending on media breakpoints

Tags: angular, typescript, media-queries

```
@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
    private _tUrl = 'this should be on desktop'; 
    private _tUrl = 'this should be on mobile'; 
}
```

This is for the API call. I only want to use one depend on device size.

Comment: I suggest you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript

Comment: I'm using typescript from angular service for calling the API. Don't think the link is helpful

Comment: Since even the angular service runs on the client side, it's able to get access to the `window` object. If that's not the case, you have to be more specific where your code runs.

Comment: @WilnarVincent Have you tried the solution suggested in my answer below?

Comment: do you need to set the property only once when the service is instantiated or should it change depending on the current screen size (reactive)?

Comment: Want it to change depending on the current screen size.

Comment: got it, and what is it that you want to do with the value? http calls?

Comment: yes, i'm sorry if I don't have information for this question. I'm new at angular.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following logic:

```
@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
    ...

   fetchFromBackEnd():Observable<Foo>{
      // somehow get the current endpoint
      // and call a method from angular´s HttpClient
      // with the endpoint
   }
}
```

Considering this scenario, you have 2 pathways that lead to a possible solution:

- Reactive (async)
- Non reactive (sync)

The first one would look more or less like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import {switchMap, take}from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
   url$: Observable<string>;

   constructor(){
     this.url$ = this.createUrlStream();
   }

   fetchFromBackEnd():Observable<Foo>{
      const fetch: string => Observable<Foo> = (url) => this.http.get<Foo>(url);
      return this.url$.pipe(take(1),switchMap(url => fetch(url)); 
   }

   private createUrlStream():Observable<string>{
      // logic to map media query changes to a URL
   }
}
```

The non reactive approach would look like:

```
@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
   get url(): string {
     // logic to synchronously match the current media breakpoints
     // to a URL
   }

   fetchFromBackEnd():Observable<Foo>{
      return this.http<Foo>(this.url);
   }
}
```

In order to not reinvent the wheel or **directly deal** with the `window` object or other implementation details, I would suggest you to **introduce another layer of abstraction** by using the [LayoutModule](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) of the angular material CDK lib.

By using the [BreakpointObserver](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#breakpointobserver) provided by the lib, the 2nd implementation would look like this:

```
@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
   get url(): string {
     return this.isMobile ? "mobileurl" : "desktopurl";
   }

   private get isMobile():boolean {
      // example
      return this.bpObserver.isMatched('(max-width: 599px)')
   }

   constructor(private bpObserver: BreakPointObserver){

   }

   fetchFromBackEnd():Observable<Foo>{
      return this.http<Foo>(this.url);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check using `window.matchmedia` to check viewport width of the device and then call API depend on device size. like this -

```
@Injectable() export class HomeService {   
 constructor(){
   let mq = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width:640px)")
   if (mq.matches) {
        this._tUrl = 'this should be on desktop'; 
   }
   else { this._tUrl = 'this should be on mobile';  }
   ...........
 }
```

Comment: Downvoter's let me know where I am wrong here? instead of downvoting only

Comment: will surely try this one

Comment: accessing DOM directly is a bad practice in Angular