# How to get viewport height, on mobile, independent from the current hide/show state of URL bar?

Tags: javascript, mobile, height, viewport, address-bar

On mobile (e.g. Chrome on Android) the viewport height changes depending on whether the URL/Address bar is hidden or not, which changes depending on whether you're scrolling up or down on the page.

Given this, I need 2 variables:

1. Viewport height if URL bar were showing (regardless of actual state).
2. Viewport height if URL bar were **not** showing (regardless of actual state).

In other words: "min" and "max" viewport heights. How would I go about doing that? I only know how to get:

- Viewport height given current state of URL bar (showing/not-showing).

By doing: `Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0)` (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/473368).

Comment: I guess that is only possible in the native programming language of the mobile. %)P Other idea, go and collect the `data` when ever possible. Think of user somewhen scrolls up and down. And the corresponding behaviour of the `URL-Bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, use the `window.outerHeight` property:

> `Window.outerHeight` gets the height in pixels of the whole browser window. It represents the height of the whole browser window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

To expand your function, just compare `window.outerHeight` and `window.innerHeight`:

```js
let maxHeight = Math.max(window.innerHeight || 0, window.outerHeight || 0);
let minHeight = Math.min(window.innerHeight || 0, window.outerHeight || 0);
console.log(maxHeight, minHeight);
```

Comment: This just gives you **current-viewport-height** and **whole-window-height**. What I actually need is **viewport-height-without-url-bar** and **viewport-height-with-url-bar**. **whole-window-height** _is not_ **viewport-height-without-url-bar**.