# Getting the viewport size for a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, viewport

Is there any way for a Google App Script to find out what the visible width in the current sheet is in a Google Spreadsheet? There doesn't appear to be, but I thought I'd see if anyone knew of one. I'm trying to rearrange/resize my columns to work nicely with devices of various sizes.

Is there anything you could add that would dynamically size to 100% and could be measured by GAS? Again, I couldn't find anything, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Apps Script runs in Google's servers, not your browser (or mobile app), so in general terms, Apps Script has no idea if there is even a UI attached. In some specific instances you can access [`SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) but as you state, there is no feedback available here.

Comment: I think this might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/7215091).

Comment: You would need to open a dialog box with JavaScript in a `<script>` tag, run the client side JavaScript, and then make a call to the server with `google.script.run.myFunctionName()`

Comment: A dialog box like I would get from 
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
} ? When I create that dialog box, it is contained in a 500px box, which I can measure with a script function, but that doesn't get me the width of the document.