# Get only currently visible text

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I know I can get the whole body of a document with `context.document.body.getOoxml()` and the current selection with `context.document.getSelection()`, however I can't find a way to establish what is currently on screen and what is not...

Is there a method in the Word Office JS api to retrieve only the content currently displayed on the screen?

Comment: Even the COM APIs don't have a method or property for this, if you mean visible in the Word application window (as opposed to being hidden in the document)...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a solution for this. The way some of the JavaScript libraries in web pages are able figure out this problem is through the view port.

Example here: https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery

See another helpful SO answer here: [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

Now - Word however uses HTML as a way of formatting - and not as a way of directly displaying things. So even if you could run the same library on the HTML - it wouldn't have the same context.

The best you could do is to get the height of the visible space (which should be the same height as your add-in frame) and attempt to do some mapping. You would have some weird edge cases though, like if the font-size is different, or you have a page-break in the view etc...

Comment: FWIW Word does not use HTML for formatting or anything else. It can only import/export the format using a converter.

Comment: In this context Word uses HTML for formatting / converter or not - that doesn't matter. You can inject styled HTML using a Web add-in and Word would display it as it should be displayed on an HTML page. The article solutions however require a browser and access to viewport. Since Word doesn't have this functionality - there isn't a solution for this - please read the first sentence.