# How to Get position of a div or an image in the div (top and left position) and use those values in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which is dynamic and using bootstrap. I want to create an animation into it where the dynamic thumbnails in div class="col-md-4" on clicking zoom from there position to 100% at the center of the container.

I am to create an on click effect to zoom the image but not from the position of the div, but from the center of the page. I am trying positioning of the image.

```js
x = document.getElementById("Image")

t = x.top;
l = x.left;

function hello() {
x.style.top = x.top + "px";
x.style.left = x.left + "px";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <img id="Image" src="abc.jpg">
  <h2>ABC</h2>
</div>
```

But no luck. If anyone can help me out. Please do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

`x.getBoundingClientRect()` it will give you the absolute position of the element to the document.

You can get the viewport's height and width using this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)

From there you can get the proper offset you're looking for.