# Resize button according to screen size

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

For a button,  by default Bootstrap 4 [allow you to set default button "size"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/) between : xs, sm, md, lg, xl.

So, in my code, small screen first, i use sm size for screen <576px :

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"></button>`

But for xl screen ≥1200px, need i to change size attribute or something else with Bootstrap to adjust button size ?

I don't really understand Bootstrap responsive behavior for button and 'size' attribute between small and large screen.

Thanks.

Comment: i'd already seen the `btn-block` class like : 
`class="btn btn-success btn-block" `
Is it the best solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Vue.js documentation, i had finally computed my CSS class dynamically according to `window.onresize`event call in `mounted ()` function.

> **Example :**

Here is my Bootstrap button :

```
<b-button :size="nsize" variant="outline-success" class="my-2 my-sm-0">
     <font-awesome-icon icon="search"/>
</b-button>
```

Here is my function in App.vue file:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'topnavbar',
  data () {
    return {      
      nsize: "sm",
      mediaWidth: Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
    }
  },
  mounted () {    
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateSize, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onresize", this.updateSize);
    }
  },
  methods : {
    updateSize: function (){    
      let sizeEl = "md";  
      let width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
      if(width <= 576){
        sizeEl = "sm";
      }
      this.nsize = sizeEl;      
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

***Sources***:

- [Get the browser viewport dimensions with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript)
- https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built out of the box for responsive buttons in bootstrap, you'd probably be better off extending the existing bootstrap button sizes in sass/media queries ie

```
.responsive-button {
  @media (min-width: 576px) { @extend .btn-sm }
  @media (min-width: 768px) { @extend .btn-md }
}
```

I haven't tested this so may need to research a bit further but hopefully this gets you on track :)

Comment: nope, it's using scss. If you don't have access to this you could write it like `@media (min-width: 576px) { .responsive-button { padding: 20px; background-color: blue; } }` etc, there may be some code duplication doing this though cos I don't think you can extend bootstrap classes in plain css

Comment: I'd tried and unfortunately it was also my conclusion. Indeed, I could use media queries but it's really not efficient...

Comment: Another 'inefficient' solution would be to have a button for each viewport, so button one would be `<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm d-md-none">`, two `<button class ="btn btn-success btn-md d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">`, three `<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">` etc.

Comment: I will try this solution, and come back. Thanks Rixcy.