# ScrollIntoView bugged in firefox when using SVG

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I have a vertically long SVG image that I need to scroll to some specific element with a specific id.

```
const el = document.getElementById(id);
el.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'center'
});
```

This works fine in chrome but Firefox scrolls into view the top of the SVG file, not the selected element.

I reproduced the bug in a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wkoiwq

https://react-wkoiwq.stackblitz.io

In chrome the #hotplate element is moved to the center while in firefox the top of the SVG is moved to the center.

Try changing `center`, with `start` and `end` to see the effect.

Is there a way to fix / avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps doing it manually is the right solution:

- [`el.getBoundingClientRect().top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the position relative to the viewport.
- [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) to get the current viewport offset.
- [`document.clientHeight`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/1026) to get the viewport height (without the scrollbar)
- Calculate the required offset (relative to the document element), and use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) to scroll.

For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById("hotplate");

// { block: "top" } behavior:
let newScrollY = window.pageYOffset + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

// adjust to behave like { block: "center" }
newScrollY = newScrollY - document.documentElement.clientHeight/2;

window.scrollTo({top: newScrollY, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the main issue is that Firefox animates to the original position of the element #hotplate which the boundaries of the parent SVG. Firefox does not account for y attribute.

To overcome this you can wrap your svg code in a container and add a span that has the same position as the svg child element with an absolute position.

You can change your HTML to:

```
<div class='container'>
   <span id='hotplate-ref"></span>
   <svg>.....</svg>
</div>
```

and then add to your CSS:

```
.container
{
  position: relative;
}

#hotplate-ref
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1703px; /* includes margin top of svg (1400px) + y attribute of svg element (503px) */
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and finally change "componentDidMount()" to this:

```
    const el = document.getElementById("hotplate-ref");
    el.scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth', 
      block: 'start' 
    });
```

I tested the code in both Chrome and FF and it worked fine.

Obviously, you can do this with other svg child elements as well.