# window.onresize event, innerHeight and innerWidth return wrong values on ipad chrome browser

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

On ipad chrome browser, the `innerWidth`/`innerHeight` values remain the same following the first `window.onresize` event.
This problem is not seen in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the browser viewport dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/how-to-get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

It is working, I added some settimeout after getting window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth correctly.