# How to get the fractional width and height of the browser viewport?

Tags: javascript

I'm not talking about getting a rounded size, I need to get the fractional one.

An only way I know is to create a new `div` element with the `position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0` properties set and append it to the `body` element after it's done, I can get a fractional size with `getBoundingClientRect`.

But it's slow, it's very slow. This approach stops the rest JS code from being executed until the DOM manipulations and calculations are done.

Is there a way of doing this without an expensive approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the browser viewport dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/how-to-get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions)

Comment: In CSS you can use `vw` (viewport width) and `vh` (viewport height). For example `80vw` is 80% of the viewport's width.

Comment: @M.AShahbazi I'm not sure because I need `fractional` values!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
let viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Sorry! Could I ask you a question!? Have you read my post?

Comment: @Katya please give me an example of what a 'fractional' value might look like

Comment: 50.52 is fractional. 51 is rounded

Comment: @Katya what unit do you need this as? 50.52 px? 50.52 cm? 50.52%?

Comment: @Katya well a pixel cannot be cut in half physically, so I'm convinced there can't be a viewport height that's not an integer. So when `window.innerHeight` returns something like `52`, it's probably the precise value, not rounded.

Comment: Trust me, it can be!!! Did you hear something about `pixelRatio`, `scaling`, `4k monitors`. In fact, this list can be longer. It seems to me I've found a solution to my question, but I need to test it and if it works correctly. I give my answer here.