# How to apply this Javascript code on desktop only?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scroll, media-queries

I want to modify this code to make it work only on dekstop devices.

For my case, dekstop is anything above 640px.

Here is the original code:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("shopify-section-header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("shopify-section-header").style.top = "-150px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
if (window.innerWidth > 640) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
      document.getElementById("shopify-section-header").style.top = "0";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("shopify-section-header").style.top = "-150px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  }
 }
```

From the MDN Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth):

> The read-only Window property innerWidth returns the interior width of the window in pixels. This includes the width of the vertical scroll bar, if one is present.
>
> More precisely, innerWidth returns the width of the window's layout viewport. The interior height of the window—the height of the layout viewport—can be obtained from the innerHeight property.

Alternatives:

- If you can use jQuery: `$(window).width()`
- `document.documentElement.clientWidth` matches the `@media` queries in css **but only when there is no scrollbar**
- `window.innerWidth` exactly matches css `@media` queries.

For more about the differences, see [How to get the browser viewport dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/how-to-get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions/8876069#8876069)