# Hide certain items when their flexbox container overflows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider this flexbox container with a few items. A few random ones tagged with `.hide-on-overflow`

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1 </div>
  <div class="item hide-on-overflow">Item 2 </div>
  <div class="item hide-on-overflow">Item 3 </div>
  <div class="item ">Item 4 </div>
  <div class="item hide-on-overflow">Item 5 </div>
</div>
```

CSS to set this up as a flexbox row

```
#container {
  display: flex; 
}

.item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.hide-on-overflow { }
```

Now I would like the items tagged with `.hide-on-overflow` to disappear when `#container` begins to overflow. The question is not how to hide them (I would use `display: none;`), but how to detect the container overflowing. This is intended as a flexible solution instead of using a media query on the entire window width (thus estimating when the container would overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this can be done with CSS. But I would do it in JavaScript using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Note that this an example of just one way to do this, there are possibly much better ways.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container")
// elements to hide when overflowing
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".hide-on-overflow")
// lastItem with which we detect if we are overflowing
const lastItem = container.lastElementChild

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
    root:       null,  // intersect with viewport
    rootMargin: '0px', // no margin when computing intersections
    threshold:  1.0,   // execute callback when every pixel is visible/hidden
})
observer.observe(lastItem)

let breakpoint = 0 // breakpoint where we started to overflow
// Intersection Observer callback, which is called when no pixels of lastItem
// are visible anymore.
function callback(entries, observer) {
    for (const entry of entries) {
        if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
            // Save current viewport width when we hide the elements.
            breakpoint = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
            for (const element of elements) {
                element.style.display = "none"
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onresize = function() {
    // If we resize before the breakpoint is set, do nothing.
    if (breakpoint === 0) {
        return
    }

    // Viewport width
    vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
    if (vw > breakpoint) {
        for (const element of elements) {
            element.style.display = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a simple summary of what this does. To best understand it, make sure to know the basics of Intersection Observer and read the code.

Using Intersection Observer we observe whether `lastItem` (last item in `#container`) is visible depending on the viewport. If it is not, it means we are overflowing. When this happens, we save the viewport width and hide the `hide-on-overflow` elements.

Then using a `resize` event listener, we display the `hide-on-overflow` elements when the current viewport width is larger than the viewport width of when we started overflowing.

We cannot use Intersection Observer for both ways as the `lastItem` is no longer visible when we hide it and the `callback` is not called back anymore. That is why we use the `breakpoint` variable and the `resize` event listener.

Viewport width is retrieved like it is described in [javascript - How to get browser viewport dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069).